# Autolayout + Sizing classes migration and iPad app to universal?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios8, autolayout

My existing iPad app uses a storyboard without auto layout in landscape mode.

I figured I could apply auto layout constraints, then turn on sizing classes.

I hoped I could do one screen at a time, testing by turning sizing classes on an off. By doing so I could keep existing sizes and positions and use them in default auto layout constants?

However, after doing my first screen I can't find a sizing class which will make my auto layout constraint work / look good.

I'm lost as to how to proceed? Should I turn on auto layout and sizing classes before adding any autolayout constraints? also if I do this what sizing class will best suit my existing iPad landscape layout?

Answer (score 0):

1) First of all, turn on Auto Layout and set your views correctly.

2) If you have changes between iPad and iPhone (Actually, different sizes), just duplicate the modified constraints, and mark the correct constraint as installed when you change the size class.

[image]

3) You can open assistant panel, and choose preview In order to see how it looks both on iPhone and iPad.

[image]

Comment: So when do I turn on sizing classes? and what size class should I use to gain my current positions as constants, so will I not be able to use them :( ?

Comment: First set constraints for iPhone/General (Any Any). Then change size class to iPad (Let's say Normal Normal). In that state, all the constraints of the AnyAny will stay, unless you uninstall them and create a new one. Got it?

Comment: So turn on autolayout and sizing classes before adding any constraints ?

Comment: You cannot add constraints without turning on Autolayout. Then add constraints, and after that change to other size class and do modifications on your constraints. Think it's like subclassing - you create your constraints on AnyAny, and then change size class and change what your want.

Comment: So just to be clear turn on both before doing anything?

Comment: Yes, that will be fine. just try :)

Comment: OK thanks, I was quite surprised turning sizing classes on after auto layout, that it screwed things up so badly. Thought my constraints would look good on at least one size :(